# Is there any formula of summation of multiple sine waves?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, optimization

I lastly want to find $\{s_i\}_i$ such that
$$\min_t \left[\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\cos{(2\pi f_i t)}\right]=K,$$
where $\{f_i\}_i$ and $K$ are given.

---

I began to start when $n=2$, so I first tried to find $t^*$ that minimizes
$$f(t) := a_1 \cos(2\pi f_1 t) + a_2 \cos(2\pi f_2 t).$$
Thus, I tried to find $t$ that satisfies the following two equations:
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{df(t)}{dt} = -2a_1\pi f_1 \sin(2\pi f_1t) - 2a_2\pi f_2\sin(2\pi f_2t)=0,\\
\displaystyle\frac{d^2 f(t)}{dt^2} = -4a_1\pi^2f_1^2\cos(2\pi f_1t) - 4a_2\pi^2f_2^2\cos(2\pi f_2t) > 0.
\end{cases}

But I failed...... :(

Is there any formula of solving $$\alpha\sin(At) + \beta\sin(Bt)=0 \quad??$$

Comment: I cannot understand your question since there is no $s_i$ in the equation you give.

Comment: can I use arc tangent in a sum of two sine functions, not a sum of one sine and one cosine?

Comment: Oops, I guess I had mis-read that equation.  It might be difficult to solve in general.  You can try using Euler's formula.  Of course there's always $t=0$.